# Swift Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplicationStateInactive'

Tags: ios, swift, compilation

In my Swift code to handle push notification I have this line:

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive  || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
}
```

Which cause the compilation error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplicationStateInactive'

Am I missing some import files?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the Objective-C enum value and not the Swift enum value?

Comment: What is the Swift equivalent? I can not find the doc for that

Comment: The docs for `UIApplicationState` show the value for both languages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently your are using the identifiers for Objective-C. You need to use the identifier for swift:

```
UIApplicationState.Inactive // equals UIApplicationStateInactive
UIApplicationState.Background // equals UIApplicationStateBackground
```

Apple documentation for:

- [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/UIApplicationState)
- [Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIApplicationState)

You can check the documentation for both languages in the Apple Documentation and choose the language in the top right corner.

Comment: Perfect. Could you provide the links for the related doc? I suppose all the Objective-C enums are changed in Swift. Hopefully there is a central doc for that. Thanks

Comment: Done. The Apple Doc is available for both languages