# Function not working in Swift 2. (Unresolved identifier for defined variable)

Tags: xcode, swift, function, variables, swift-playground

I'm trying to move learn Swift 2 coming from a background of Python.  Started making a really simple function that counts the G's and C's.  I'm getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'SEQ'` on the line `var length: Float = Float(SEQ.characters.count)`

**What am I doing wrong? It's definitely defined in the beginning of the function?**

Tried the following posts:

[Swift Use of unresolved identifier 'UIApplicationStateInactive'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363787/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier-uiapplicationstateinactive)

[Swift - Use of unresolved identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950097/swift-use-of-unresolved-identifier)

```
func GC(input_seq: String) -> Float {
    let SEQ = input_seq.uppercaseString
    var counter = 0.0
    for nt in SEQ.characters {
        if (nt == "G") {
            var counter = counter + 1
        }
        if (nt == "C") {
            var counter = counter + 1
            }
        }
    }
    var length: Float = Float(SEQ.characters.count)

    return counter/length
}

let query_seq = "ATGGGGCTTTTGA"
GC(query_seq)
```

Comment: Your curly braces do not match properly, so that `var length : Float = ...` is *outside* of the function body.

Comment: if you make an answer for it i can mark it right.  im still getting used to the curly brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you do wrong.

1. You are creating a Double counter (not a Float as you probably intended): `var counter = 0.0`

You really need it as an integer since it's a counter. You can convert it to a Float later.  `var counter = 0` will create an `Int` variable

2. you are creating a second and a third local variables in the if blocks:

   `if (nt == "G") {
       var counter = counter + 1
   }`

I don't think you understand the basics and might be beneficial for you to start reading the Swift book from the beginning.

3. This is really an improvement - you can use a shorthands:

`counter = counter + 1`  to `counter += 1` or even `counter++`

Here is a working version of your code:

```
func GC(input_seq: String) -> Float {
    let SEQ = input_seq.uppercaseString
    var counter = 0
    for nt in SEQ.characters {
        if (nt == "G") {
            counter++
        }
        if (nt == "C") {
            counter++
        }
    }

    return Float(counter)/Float(SEQ.characters.count)
}

let query_seq = "ATGGGGCTTTTGA"
GC(query_seq)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yea I agree, I am taking an online Swift class on Coursera.  Every time they do a new tutorial I try to expand on it.  You're right, I should read the book from the beginning tho.  Thanks for this explanation, it really helps.